# Button not properly tweeting text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

I have this [codePen](http://codepen.io/templenaylor/pen/NdvbaP?editors=1010) that is a random quote generator. 
I also have a tweet button that should tweet the quote generated. 
Currently when pressing it, it tweets another random quote, not the current quote displayed. Here is the function:

```
$(".twitter-share-button").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("href", 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + randomNumber);
  });

function tweetIt(){
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + quotes[randomNumber]);
}
```

I tried solving this by selecting the current ID the quote is in but to no avail:

```
function tweetIt(){
  var tweet = document.getElementById('quote').value;
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + quotes[randomNumber]);
};
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing your current quote within an element with the id of "quoteDisplay":

```
function newQuote() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    // The content for your tweet is being set here
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
};
```

So you'll need to target the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property for that particular element if you want to tweet the current quote :

```
function tweetIt(){
  // Get the contents of your current tweet
  var tweet = document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').textContent;
  // Open a new window with that tweet content
  window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + tweet);
};
```

Comment: Don't use `innerText`. It's not standard and doesn't exist in FireFox. Use `textContent`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this clearly. Also, thank you @Barmar

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for that, I've adjusted the answer as well.